# "Не залежати на" or "не залежати від"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова, вживання-слів

I've seen both of these phrases used for the seemingly same purpose. Someone or something is not dependent on someone or something.

[Не залежати на](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=LlqECwAAQBAJ&pg=PT119&lpg=PT119&dq="%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%B0"&source=bl&ots=hWr-bgYuvg&sig=8pOi4F4dymrXhZEW8QP0jAOnnIs&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigrfX76dHSAhXM1iwKHcKjBI0Q6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%22&f=false):

> А все тому, що мені не залежить на славі.

[Не залежати від](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=8F2ECwAAQBAJ&pg=PT231&dq="%D1%86%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4"&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS79ih69HSAhUF1ywKHRRVC1UQ6AEIQzAI#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%22&f=false):

> Хіба це не залежить від внутрішньої ... настанови...

As we can see, the same author (Emma Andijewska) uses both "на" and "від".

Are both of them OK to use? Is one of them grammatically right and the other colloquial?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Цитата з журналу «Науковий вісник Чернівецького університету. Слов'янська філологія» ([випуск 276–277, 2006](//books.google.com/books?id=A2w7AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%22)):

> **Залежати на чому** — мати для когось значення, бути предметом зацікавлення:
>
> > Врешті з тоjу бібліотекоjу міні не вдалось доси нічогісінько, навіть здобути на час 2-3 потрібні книжки; ані се, ані те, — так шчо jа вже далі махну рукоjу, хоть міні, jако ред[акторові] «Гр[омадського] Др[уга]» мусить залежати на тім, шчо б вона допаласьа хоть в такі руки, котрі будуть з неї користати, от напр[иклад] «Етн[ографічно]-стат[истичному] Кружкови». ([Павлик, т. IV, с. 250](//books.google.com/books?id=7fIKAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BC%22)).

Тобто:

- Звичайне «***перший* залежить від *другого***» — це пряме значення слова «[залежати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zalezhaty) 1».
- Застаріле «***першому* залежить на *другому***» означає «*перший* зацікавлений у *другому*», «*другий* має значення для *першого*». Часто вживається з «має»/«мусить»/«повинно»: «*першому* має залежати на *другому*». Але є варіанти і без «має»/«мусить»/«повинно»:

  > У 1733 р. почалося в Польщі безкоролівя й подуло воєнним вітром, а москалям почало залежати на запоріжцях; з царської канцелярії вислано тоді до Запоріжжя грамоту з амнестією. *<sub>//Іван Круп'якевич, Микола Голубець «Велика історія України» (Львів — 1935, Вінніпег — 1948, Львів — 1993), том II, розділ «Упадок Гетьманщини», підрозділ «Поворот запоріжців на Україну».</sub>*

---

Quote from the journal «Науковий вісник Чернівецького університету. Слов'янська філологія» ([issue 276–277, 2006](//books.google.com/books?id=A2w7AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83%22)):

> **Залежати на чому** — мати для когось значення, бути предметом зацікавлення:
>
> > Врешті з тоjу бібліотекоjу міні не вдалось доси нічогісінько, навіть здобути на час 2-3 потрібні книжки; ані се, ані те, — так шчо jа вже далі махну рукоjу, хоть міні, jако ред[акторові] «Гр[омадського] Др[уга]» мусить залежати на тім, шчо б вона допаласьа хоть в такі руки, котрі будуть з неї користати, от напр[иклад] «Етн[ографічно]-стат[истичному] Кружкови». ([Павлик, т. IV, с. 250](//books.google.com/books?id=7fIKAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D1%96%D0%BC%22)).

Thus:

- Regular “***A<sub>NOM</sub>* залежить від *B<sub>GEN</sub>***” means “*A* depends on *B*”.
- Obsolete “***A<sub>DAT</sub>* залежить на *B<sub>LOC</sub>***” means “*А* is interested by *B*”, “*B* matters for *A*”. It's often used as “*A<sub>DAT</sub>* має/мусить/повинно залежати на *B<sub>LOC</sub>*” (“*B* should/must/etc matter for *A*”). Usages without “should”/“must”/etc are also present:

  > У 1733 р. почалося в Польщі безкоролівя й подуло воєнним вітром, а москалям почало залежати на запоріжцях; з царської канцелярії вислано тоді до Запоріжжя грамоту з амнестією. *<sub>//Ivan Krypyakevych, Mykola Holubets «Велика історія України» (Lviv — 1935, Winnipeg — 1948, Lviv — 1993), volume II, chapter «Упадок Гетьманщини», subchapter «Поворот запоріжців на Україну».</sub>*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's very helpful. Is it that obsolete though? Would people understand me if I said "мені не залежить на грошах?". Is it the right way to say it? Is genitive "місцевий" here cause of the preposition "на" or do I get it wrong?

Comment: @P.Vovk, "*Is it that obsolete though?*" To be honest, I do not know. I've never heard such construction before and it seems to occur rarely in literature; on the other hand, modern authors use it too — so it may be a gap in my education rather than a real obsoleteness. "*Is genitive "місцевий" here cause of the preposition "на"[…]?*" Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: thanks, I'll try using it here and there and see if it works, I like the way it sounds. Oh, I've mixed it up, sorry, you've written everything right. I've confused the upper and the lower explanations.

Answer (score 0):

«(Не) залежати на» in modern Ukrainian is not very typical. Probably you'll be misunderstood if you use it.

«(Не) залежати від» is equal to "(do not) depend on" and widely used nowadays.

Comment: В принципі згоден на 100%, хоча знов таки без достатньої аргументації. (Ось сучасний автор Оксана Забужко «не залежати на» вживає — як довести, що його не зрозуміють?) І знов таки, як мені здається, відповідь нічого не додає (і значення, і те, що «не залежати на» — застаріле, сказане в іншій відповіді), хоч, може, і недостатньо виразно.

Comment: Схоже, про Забужко більше говорять, ніж справді її читають (а читаючи, невідомо, чи справді розуміють її так, як їй того б хотілося) — не можна сказати, що її мова є зразком для масового наслідування. Якщо в сучасній публіцистиці (при тому, що журналісти загалом не гребують усілякою мовною екзотикою) «залежати на» практично відсутнє, то, мабуть, журналісти або не знають про таку конструкцію, або сприймають її як помилку.

Comment: @PYPY Будь ласка, додайте посилання на джерела, які підтверджують вашу думку щоб зробити ваш допис кращим. Дякую!